# Google Maps not showing my phone in "Send to your phone"

Tags: google-maps

When you search some place in Google Maps, you have the option to "send" that place to your phone (it just sends a notification to the google maps app).

I used it a lot but while ago it disappeared my phone, as it is not linked so I can't send it:

[image]

I've followed the "Connect a device" help steps and nothing changed. I have the app in my phone, and my account is linked, the same account that I am using in the browser.

I've searched a lot and this is the closest topic I've found:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/e6pfZ5U5Gw8

Some things to know:

- I have many accounts linked in my phone and in my browser, but I am using the same one in both devices.
- I've tried in Incognito mode with no luck.
- In the app settings, I've turned on "Sent from desktop maps" notifications.
- I am using iOS 10, but this started happening before, with iOS 9.

What should I do in order to solve this?

Comment: Do you have the latest version of Maps installed on your phone?

Comment: @user3554664 yes, and I am using iOS

Comment: Not sure what the issue is. At first I thought maybe it's that notifications are off for the app, but I realized on my device I half the time it's missing too. Can't figure out why.

Comment: This could very well be something that Apple has disabled.

Comment: @AlE. yes, I'm logged. How would Apple disable this? It is just an app notification..

Comment: Who knows why Apple does anything?

Comment: Sorry, shouldn't be so snarky. I'm afraid I can't help; I don't use an iPhone. Of course, it works perfectly on my Android phone.

Comment: More likely than apply disabling it, it's a bug with the iOS version.